# Access the element out of size in C++ vector

Tags: c++, vector, size, capacity

Today I try something like this in VS2012 and Max OS 10.7

```
    vector<int> vec;
    vector<int> vec2;
    for(int i = 0;i < 100 ;i++){
        vec.push_back(i);
    }

    cout << "size: " << vec.size() << endl;
    cout << "capacity: " << vec.capacity() << endl;
    cout << vec[127] << endl;
    //vec2.reserve(10);
    fill_n(vec.begin(),128,-1);
    cout << vec[127] << endl;
    return 0;
```

as we know the size of vector is the real number of elements in the container, the code above can cause runtime error in VS2012, but it works fine on Max OS, and I try it in [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) and also run successfully, I am not sure if something wrong with the definition of size and capacity, why I can access element out of size?

PS: the capacity at this situation on my computer is 141 on VS2012 and 128 on Mac OS and Ideone.com

Comment: By the way, `std::iota` exists.

Comment: "Works" is a relative term. Try `vec.at(127)`, and then think about the term **undefined behavior**.

Comment: It is the responsibility of the the user of the vector to make sure you don't access beyond the end of the allocated space. This is done to make sure speed is optimal for `operator[]`. If you want runtime validation use `at()` this throws an exception if you exceed the bounds of the array (but is slower because of the checks).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::vector` operator `[]` won't throw any out of range error. It's a undefined behaviour to access element greater than the vector size using `[]` operator.

Use [`std::vector::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) instead, which throws [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range)

Answer (score 0):

Bump into this problem, I try to elaborate the answer from @P0W.

### #1 Access element(s) of the 2d vector

If someone wants to access the elements of the 2d vector,

one should do the following and aware of the API `2dvector.at(row#).at(col#)`

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <vector<int> > vi;
    vi.push_back( vector <int>() );    // add empty 1d vector
    vi.at(0).push_back( 1 );           // push 1st element
    cout << vi.at(0).at(0) << endl;    // access element of 2d vector and prints 1
    vi.at(0).at(0) = 2;                // change number
    cout << vi.at(0).at(0) << endl;    // access element of 2d vector and prints 2
}
```

### #2 `std::out_of_range`

if you have difficulty finding the example of `std::out_of_range`, here is one

#### example code

```
// out_of_range example
#include <iostream>       // std::cerr
#include <stdexcept>      // std::out_of_range
#include <vector>         // std::vector

int main (void) {
  std::vector<int> myvector(10);
  try {
    myvector.at(20)=100;      // vector::at throws an out-of-range
  }
  catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) {
    std::cerr << "Out of Range error: " << oor.what() << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

#### output

```
Out of Range error: vector::_M_range_check
```

Comment: more info about `std::out_of_range`(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/out_of_range/)