# How to retrieve the first element of each vector of a matrix in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

Given that the matrix is defined as:

```
using matrix = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;
```

I'm trying to print the first element of each vector in this matrix.

```
std::vector<double> print_first_val(const matrix& all_val)

{
    std::vector<double> first_vals;

    long unsigned int size_of = all_val.size();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size_of; i++)
    {
        int num = all_val[i][0];
        first_vals.push_back(num);
    }
    return first_vals;

int main()
{
    matrix input { { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4 }, { -1, 1, 1.2, 2, 3.4, 4, 4 }, { 0, 3, 3, 4.5 } };

    auto output_2 = print_first_val(input);
    for (auto x : output_2) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
}
```

however, I'm getting this error:

`conversion from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<double>, double>::value_type’ {aka ‘double’} to ‘int’ may change value [-Werror=float-conversion]`

This error occured at the line where  `int num = all_val[i][0];` is performed.

I really have no idea what's going on here and I'm quite new to `C++` so it must be pretty obvious and I'm not getting it. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Which line exactly does that happen in? What is going on in that line that could explain the warning? BTW: You should have extracted a [mcve] from your code, it would probably have pointed you at the error already.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt just updated the description of the problem

Comment: Why do convert a `double` to `int`? `all_val[i][0]` is a `double` and `num` is a `int`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I'll need that double to perform a larger operation in the future

Comment: change `int num` to `auto num`

Comment: @M.M thanks! That solved the issue, but why do I need to do that? what is the problem with num being an int?

Comment: well, what happens if you try and store `3.14` into an `int` ?

Comment: @M.M  Oh, got it, now it sound so silly.

Comment: Keep in mind that ```double``` is a double precision floating point type. If you just need a larger integer you can use ```long```or ```long long```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to save as int:

```cpp
int num = all_val[i][0];
```

What is supposed to be a double:

```
using matrix = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;
```

So change the type specifier of `num` to either `double` or `auto`:

```cpp
auto num = all_val[i][0];
```

Below, a reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using matrix = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;

std::vector<double> print_first_val(const matrix& all_val)
{
    std::vector<double> first_vals;

    long unsigned int size_of = all_val.size();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size_of; i++)
    {
        auto num = all_val[i][0];
        first_vals.push_back(num);
    }
    return first_vals;

}

int main()
{
    matrix input { { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4 }, { -1, 1, 1.2, 2, 3.4, 4, 4 }, { 0, 3, 3, 4.5 } };

    auto output_2 = print_first_val(input);
    for (auto x : output_2) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
}
```

Or set the compile flag:

`-Wno-error=float-conversion`

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @BiOS's explanation, the vector size should be check before accessing the first element.

To read more: Access the element out of size in C++ vector
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19262233/15254914